# Dell XPS 13 9350 ubuntu gnome boot and wifi issues

Tags: boot, wireless, gnome, dell, xps

I recently bought Dell xps 13 9350 with qhd touchscreen (developer edition is not available in my country) and did reinstall to Ubuntu Gnome 16.10. I encountered boot issues.

Issue is with boot time. During the boot there is for at least 10/15 second some gray screen which then dissapears by "rolling" up and boot continues normally. First appears Dell logo, then gray screen, then loading screen. Also I can't see GRUB menu.

Because of that boot takes around 25 second what is unbelievable time with specs like mine, old docked thinkpad is faster than that. I found out it could be GRUB but even by setting it's time to 0 it didn't help at all. Even boot log thinks it takes 8 seconds for OS to boot. I also tried Unity/Elementary OS/Fedora and boot times were acceptable.

Comment: The "grey screen" is probably BIOS/UEFI, i.e., before Grub. It may or may not have to do with fastboot settings. Regarding the first part, hardware recommendations are off topic. Please edit it out and while at that please describe in more detail the boot process, where exactly it feels stuck, is it right after Dell's logo... Do you see a grub menu... etc?

Comment: edited, sorry for asking about hardware

Comment: What did you changed in BIOS/UEFI, if anything, to install Ubuntu? How did you install Ubuntu, UEFI or Legacy/CSM?

Comment: UEFI with secure boot disabled, I didn't change anything instead of disabling secure boot and boot priority (just removing CD rom)